# Testing multiple connections to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, testing, load, database-connection, connection-pooling

We're migrating SQL2005 Enterprise to SQL2012 Enterprise (on a new server too, from WIn2003 to Win2012).

Is there a way to test multiple connections to the database to prove it can take the same load as the previous server?

The application is a website, .Net3.5 with Min and Max pool size set in the connection string.

Comment: You can try with Jmeter http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and next few steps:

1. Download [jTDS JDBC Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) and drop it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter
3. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to Test Plan and configure virtual users and iterations count
4. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and provide JDBC url, driver class name and credentials

   - Database URL: `jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]`
   - JDBC Driver class name: `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`
5. Add [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler and put your query there
6. Repeat step 5 for all query types
7. Add a listener, i.e. [Aggregare Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) guide for more detailed explanation of database load testing domain.